# Ionic navigation through ion-fab

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, navigation

I'm trying to get my ion tab bar prettier with a ion-fab like that:

[image: custom ion-tab-bar]

So I had added an SVG and a ion-fab to do so but when I want to handle with the navigation with the ion fab it does not have any behavior (even in the console), for the ion tab button it's working fine.

Here is my code:

tabs.page.html

```html
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" translucent="true">
  <ion-fab-button (click)="addFood()">
    <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>

<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="boards">
      <ion-icon name="compass"></ion-icon>
      <!-- <ion-label>Accueil</ion-label> -->
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="search" class="fab-search">
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      <!-- <ion-label>Rechercher</ion-label> -->
    </ion-tab-button>

    <svg height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 50" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M100 0v50H0V0c.543 27.153 22.72 49 50 49S99.457 27.153 99.99 0h.01z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>

    <ion-tab-button tab="notifications" class="fab-notification">
      <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
      <!-- <ion-label>Notifications</ion-label> -->
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="profile">
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      <!-- <ion-label>Profile</ion-label> -->
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

my tabs.page.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.page.scss'],
})
export class TabsPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addFood() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl['/addFood'];

  }

}
```

and my tabs-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'boards',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../boards/boards.module').then((m) => m.BoardsPageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../search/search.module').then(
            (m) => m.SearchPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../notifications/notifications.module').then(
            (m) => m.NotificationsPageModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../profile/profile.module').then((m) => m.ProfilePageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'addFood',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../add-Food/add-Food.module').then((m) => m.AddFoodPageModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'boards',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

If someone can help me, I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe its just a typo. you forgot the brackets  of your navigatebyUrl call: `navigateByUrl([...])`

Comment: Try: `this.router.navigate(['/addFood']);`

Comment: @DavidB. When I'm using brackets with the navigateByUrl function VSCode throws an error 'Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | UrlTree'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)'

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib This solution throws also an error in the console. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'addFood'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'addFood'

Maybe the error is with the routing in tabs-routing.module.ts ?

Comment: What is the exact route it tries to match? Maybe you have to do a step back first. like so: `this.router.navigate(['..','/addFood'])`

Comment: You try: `this.router.navigate(['tabs/addFood']);`